# Need detailed info regarding sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I tried to search  a lot on internet about the dmv,but didn't get much. I'm unable to get,Meaning of some of the columns of this dmv. Which are:

- pg_level
- allocation_unit_id
- row_count
- numa_node
  Please share meaning of this ,if anyone could have any idea about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search for the DMV leads you to the MS Docs: [sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-buffer-descriptors-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> **page_level**    int Index level of the page. Is nullable.
>
> **allocation_unit_id**    bigint  ID of the allocation unit of the page. This value can be used to join sys.allocation_units. Is nullable.
>
> **row_count** int Number of rows on the page. Is nullable.
>
> **numa_node** int Nonuniform Memory Access node for the buffer. Is nullable.